# Daemonizing a PHP script without pcntl_fork()

Tags: php, daemon

I'm working on an embedded system that is programmed with PHP 4.4.9 - unfortunately without the PCNTL extension.

I need to create a script that runs in the background as a daemon. You'd usually do this using `fork()`, or in the PHP case, `pcntl_fork()` - but this function is not available. A shell is also missing, so I can't use the standard tools.

So, what other ways are there to cleanly start a process in the background?

Comment: PHP4 is not supported for a looong time now. You should update.

Comment: Can you set your time-limit to unlimited? - @KingCrunch: On some embedded systems you don't have that choice.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Can't unfortunately.. I would have to wait for the vendor to do this. hakre: Time limiting is not really an issue in this case.

Comment: exec("nohup php file.php  >/dev/null 2>&1 &");

Comment: @Dragon - no. The POSIX nohup does not call setsid() (although some other versions do)

Comment: php-4.4.9 has pcntl_fork(), you need to compile it with --enable-pcntl

Answer (score 1):

As kingCrunch says, you really should upgrade.

Firstly, there's more to making a daemon than just calling pcntl_fork(). You might want to read the [Unix programming FAQ](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/) and the [Unix socket FAQ](http://www.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/documentation/unix/unix-socket-faq/unix-socket-faq.html).

Next, you've not mentioned how you intend to solve the problem of concurrency - while forking is one solution to this it is not the only reason for using fork() in a daemon.

So you've really got 2 problems to solve, first how you daemonize the program then how you handle concurrency.

Note that one approach to the latter which obviates the former is to run the server from [x]inetd.

Another approach to solving the concurrency problem is to run a single threaded server and use socket_select (or stream_select) to multiplex the connections - but I'm not sure how well that is supported in PHP 4 - there is a [good example here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5758-PHP-Handle-requests-to-network-servers.html).

A simple solution would be to write a simple wrapper program in C using [daemon()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/daemon) to bootstrap the program. Or you could start it up directly from inittab. Or for a solution with complex management facilities have a look at DJB's [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html)

Comment: Thank you for your insight! However, I do know how to write a daemon, and in the given case, fork() and exec() would have been enough. I tried to formulate the question in a way to ask for an alternative to fork, and not "how to write a daemon". Still +1 for an answer that might be useful for someone else.